# how to wrap data for transferAndCall to invoke another contract?

Tags: solidity

I have a token, and a service contract. I implemented the token based on ERC677, and tried to use `transferAndCall` to call my service contract.

In my service contract, there will be several methods can be called, like `buyA(uint count, string comment)`, `rewardBB(uint amount, string comment)`.

In my understanding, in the client side, I need to wrap the method name and params as a bytes with web3 api, then in the service contract, unwrap this data, get method name, and call corresponding method with the params data.

But I got some trouble in these 2 places:
 1. how to wrap/unwrap the data
 2. for some reason, I need to use the param type of `string`, which is dynamic, when I tested the following code, but the passed string param is alway empty. When I tried with type like bytes30, it can work.

```
  bytes4 methodId = bytes4(keccak256("rewardBB(uint5,string)"));
  require(_service.call(methodId, 100, "some string of params."));
```

Any advice would be very appreciated. Thanks.